# Send reset link with Laravel Auth and encrypted user table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, encryption, forgot-password

I have a laravel 5.4 installation and I always used the default Laravel Authentication guard to handle user authentication and, mainly, the password restore process.

Now I had to encrypt the email in the `users` table using the [Elocryptfive](https://github.com/delatbabel/elocryptfive) library, so I also added `email_hash` field where the hash of the mail is stored in the db in order to easily retrieve users by their email.

I can easily authenticate users using the hash:

```
Auth::attempt([
    'email_hash' => hash('sha256', $request->get('email')), 
    'password' => $request->get('password')]
, $remember);
```

What I can't get working is the password reset process. Is there a class to override in order to retrieve users by email_hash, then access the decrypted email and send the mail, without rewriting the whole password forgotten process?

Comment: In your `ResetPasswordController.php` you can override the functions used by `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords`, you could bring up the file yourself or take a look at [the laravel api](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.html). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yeah I had to do something similar, I answered the question as a reference for anyone else having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this. I will answer my own question to provide a useful solution if someone else needs some help on the topic:

In your `ForgotPasswordController.php`, override the `sendResetLinkEmail` function:

```
/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    $hashed = hash('sha256', $request->get('email'));
    $user = User::where('email_hash', $hashed)->first();

    if (!is_null($user)) {
        $response = Password::sendResetLink(
            ['email_hash' => $hashed]
        );
    } else {
        $response = Password::INVALID_USER;
    }

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
        : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

In your `ResetPasswordController.php`, override the `credentials` function:

```
/**
 * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'email_hash' => hash('sha256', $request->get('email')),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
        'password_confirmation' => $request->get('password_confirmation'),
        'token' => $request->get('token')
    ];
}
```

Thanks to [Mike Rodham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5283119/mike-rodham) for pointing out the right direction, I hope it helps someone.

Comment: I'm bummed these controllers don't exist with Laravel Breeze in Laravel 9 